# List of questions disappearing

Tags: bug, new-nav

Under the question menu, if I click on "unanswered" and then go back to "all questions" while on the "my tags" tab, all the questions disappear. It seems that the tag filter is not clearing. I need to refresh the whole question page to get the list of questions back.

[image]

It appears that all of my favorite tags are being added to the search box on the top right corner and it is then trying to find questions that have **all** of my tags. This almost certainly will return 0 results for any user who has a wider range of favorite tags.